# R Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am trying to fit an MS GARCH model on it. However when i reaches 3 in the loop I get this error. the code I am using is the following.

```
library(MSGARCH)
    fitmlnorm <- list()
    for (i in 1:3)
    {
      spec <- CreateSpec(variance.spec = list(model = c("sGARCH")), distribution.spec = list(distribution = c("norm")), switch.spec = list(K = i))
      fitmlnorm[[i]]<-FitML(spec, y)
    }
```

the numeric data of y can be found here:
[enter link description here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!As0vrfV8OFI_gY5i5fhTDbnxv90zYg)

From testing it out, the problem seems to be with the data y as other vectors y worked fine.

Comment: Without access to your data and more information about the context in which your error is occurring it is impossible to say.

Comment: @StewartRoss Just did. If you could help

Comment: I downloaded your data and tried out the loop. On i = 3 the spec variable is being populated by the CreateSpec function but the FitML function then fails with the error you noted. I have had a look at the code of the function on GitHub but I am unable to trace where the error is arising. I do not know if the problem is a bug or if it arising from some other reason. I can only suggest referring it to the maintainers of the MSGARCH package as a potential bug, or at least as an improperly handled error.

Comment: @StewartRoss What I am finding strange is that with another data (i.e. another vector y) this same loop is working out fine [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!As0vrfV8OFI_gY5jgLqxjUcbZ7pWXQ)

Comment: I see that the loop completes without incident for your second y vector. This supports my view that it is a bug in the implementation of the FitML function, especially as the error message is 'raw' (that is to say, resulting from an unhandled exception (an error the package developers did not allow for). Sorry I can't be of more help - this one remains a bit of a mystery.

Comment: @StewartRoss Thank-you for your input, I will walk to the maintainers.